# How to set up attribute Message Group ID

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm attempting to send an SQS message to a FIFO queue. I've run into problems with the Message Group ID attribute. I thought using the MessageAttributeValue was the correct way to set up the "MessageGroupId", but AWS doesn't seem to recognize this input. What is the proper method for setting up SQS SendMessageRequest.MessageAttributes?

I've made a console project that sends a message. I've attempted a few things to set the Message Group Id attribute, but I get an exception when sending the message.

```
        SendMessageRequest sendMessageRequest = new SendMessageRequest();
        sendMessageRequest.QueueUrl = myURL;


        MessageAttributeValue mavGroupID = new MessageAttributeValue();
        mavGroupID.DataType = "MessageGroupId";
        mavGroupID.StringValue = "1";

        MessageAttributeValue mavDeDuplicateID = new    MessageAttributeValue();
        mavDeDuplicateID.DataType = "MessageDeduplicationId";
        mavDeDuplicateID.StringValue = "1";

        sendMessageRequest.MessageAttributes.Add("0", mavGroupID);
        sendMessageRequest.MessageAttributes.Add("1", mavDeDuplicateID);



        string sMyMessage = "";

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Message to send: ");
        sMyMessage = Console.ReadLine();


        sendMessageRequest.MessageBody = sMyMessage;

        SendMessageResponse sMR = amazonSQSClient.SendMessage(sendMessageRequest);
```

Amazon.SQS.AmazonSQSException: 'The request must contain the parameter MessageGroupId.'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `MessageGroupId` is specified on the `SendMessageRequest` itself. It is *not* a `MessageAttribute`.

```
SendMessageRequest.MessageGroupId = 'foo'
```

See: [SendMessageRequest Class | AWS SDK for .NET V3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/SQS/TSendMessageRequest.html)

Comment: Hi John, Thank you very much for your help. It turns out the problem was that I had an older version of the SDK installed, and this prevented me from successfully using sendMessageRequest.MessageGroupId. I had tried that, but I got build errors. So, I ended up trying the code I put up initially. Anyway, when looking at the link and your example, I realized the version had to be off. When I reinstalled the correct version, I was able to send a message. Again, thank you very much! Its nice to see this program working.

Comment: This is more straightforward than anything I've read in the so-called AWS documentation. This page https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues-moving.html says you need a `message group id` but rather unhelpfully doesn't tell you on what object etc.